# Layers array - removelayer

Tags: leaflet

I create 100 markers on a map.
As each marker may not be visible depending on 5 boolean variables, I want each marker to be embedded in a layer: 1marker = 1 layer.

The 5 conditions are in an L.control with 5 checkboxes.

Initially, all are displayed and depending on the conditions the markers

```js
singlemarker = [];
ListLayers = [];
    
// loop on the 100 markers from my database
// marker is set by the database
Object.entries(data.themes).forEach(theme => {
    var marker = L.marker([Latm, Lngm],{icon: ChxIcon});
    singlemarker.push(marker);
    ListLayers.push(new L.layerGroup(singlemarker).addTo(map));
    singlemarker = [];
})
    
console.log(ListeLayers.length)  //I obtain 100
    
map.removelayer(ListLayers[0]); //-> not working
```

Does anyone have a clue to try to solve this problem?
With many thanks

Cordially

Jean Michel

Comment: By removing a marker do you mean removing it from the DOM or just getting it hidden until the condition is back to  before ?

Comment: I found the solution by browsing the forum.
In my creation loop:

Layers.push(marker);
map.addLayer(Layers[loop]);
loop++;

and then map.removelayer(Layers[loop]);

All I have to do is configure the display with the five boolean values

Comment: I've forgotten : var Layers = new Array();